# Writing a javascript recursive async method to an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, recursion, methods

I'm trying to get some values from a complex object and turn them into a much simpler new object. Said objects can have child objects that can have child objects and so on, all with the same structure.

I've writen a code to do just that:

```
    export const u = {
        makeLinkObj: link => {
            if (link) {
                if (link.path === "*" || link.path === "/") {
                    return {
                        path: "/",
                        to: "/",
                        text: "Início",
                        icon: "home",
                        children: null,
                    };
                } else {
                    let resultObj;
                    let pathArray = link.path.split("/");
                    pathArray.shift();
                    if (pathArray.length > 0) {
                        let arrChildren;
                        if (link.children > 0) {
                            link.children.foreach(child => {
                                arrChildren.push(u.makeLinkObj(child));
                            });
                        } else {
                            arrChildren = null;
                        }
                        resultObj = {
                            path: link.path,
                            to: link.path,
                            text: link.text,
                            icon: link.meta.icon,
                            children: arrChildren,
                        };
                        return resultObj;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return "Link not defined";
            }
        },
    };
```

The problem is that it always returns the links children as empty. I think that happens because it is no an async method.
How can I make this method, that takes an argument `link` and returns an object, work asynchronously and await while the children objects are processed?

```
INPUT EXAMPLE:

{
            path: "/produtos",
            component: Produtos,
            meta: {
                breadCrumb: "Produtos", //crumb
                icon: "box",
            },
            children: [
                {
                    path: "/produtos/lista",
                    component: Produtos,
                    meta: {
                        breadCrumb: "Lista", //crumb
                        icon: "list",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
```

Is the route from my Vue router, then I use `this.$route` as test argument to test it out.

Comment: I've given this a shot, but apparently I misunderstood the question.

So to better understand the problem, I have two questions:

1) When you say "_it always returns the links children as empty_", do you mean `link.children`, and do you mean an empty array, or null, or undefined?

2) Can you explain how you think this is related to `async` and what would or should change if this function were async?

Comment: Could you show what output you're looking for from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Replace `forEach` with `map`

```
link.children.map(child => {
    u.makeLinkObj(child);
})
```

which can also be written as

```
link.children.map(u.makeLinkObj)
```

### 2. Ensure you’re testing the array length correctly using `array.length`

`link.children > 0` will always be `false`:

```js
const link = {
  children: [1,2,3,4,5]
}

console.log(link.children > 0) // <-- false
console.log(link.children.length > 0) // <-- true
```

#### References

- [`forEach` always returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value)
- [`map` will return a new array with each element being the result of the callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value)

Comment: That's not it, it doesn't make any difference in the outcome. The code is not passing the ternary operator on `link.children?`. And also, I disagree profoundly with your edit.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe a language problem then. I would still wonder why to iterate over `children` but not return the result. But hey, your code, your results :)

Comment: I am returning, recursively. I'm assigning the object returned by `u.makeLinkObj(child);` to the children property of the object to be returned by the original call.

Comment: This is your intention, but it’s not what the code does. You are actually assigning `undefined` to your `children` property. That’s because `forEach` will _always_ return `undefined`.

Comment: I see what you’re trying to do, and it’s exactly what my answer says: you can just replace all the code you’ve updated with a simple call to `map`. What’s the reason why you refuse to do that?

Comment: I don't refuse, I did that, but what I posted here is the same thing, just easier for some people to visualize. Right?

Comment: You may have a different opinion, but I find more code and indentation harder to read than just `link.children.map(u.makeLinkObj)`, aside from it also being more code and being unnecessary.

There’s another problem in your code, and it’s comparing the Array with a number when you do `if (link.children > 0) {`; this should be `link.children.length`.

Comment: The length part got me.

Comment: Well, so did the `async` assumptions and my initial edit :)

Comment: If you’re interested in my shortened, cleaned up version of the code: https://runkit.com/andreaspizsa/5dcda0a68a025700135e596c

Comment: Weird thing, It doesn't work if I don't push the elements. Just the map isn't enough...